# How to make communication between clients without a server? Node, Socket.IO, Electron

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, electron

I'm making a platform where people can play a card game together in the same room, but it's something that doesn't have a financial return, so I don't want to put the application on a server, instead, I want the person who created the room to play with friends can send their ip and their port (or something like this) so that others can connect to the room and exchange information between people in the room, using Socket.IO, how could I do that? If an http server for socket.io is needed to work, the person who created the room could be the server, if possible. (note: i'm making a desktop app using Electron.js)

Comment: A key search is for "peer to peer gaming nodejs".  You can start reading about what comes up in that Google search.

Comment: @jfriend00 This is something I needed, a "keyword" to be able to find something that would help me, thanks!

Comment: https://webrtc.org/getting-started/peer-connections